# Rails 3 - Home address without model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have all the instances of submissions shown right at my home address

*something* .com instead of something.com/submissions

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the `submissions#index` action to be your "home" page, then add this to your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
root :to => "submissions#index"
```

And make sure you get rid of `public/index.html` if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up your `routes.rb` file like so:

```
root :to => "submissions#index"
```